# iOS: read and write in a socket (tcp connection)

Tags: ios, sockets, asyncsocket

In my app I should comunicate with a server side (a little device that do as a server).

My principal operation is to write a sequence of 17 byte and read the result. I used GCDAsyncSocket but it don't give me ever a good result.

I want ask to you if is there a way to do this job in an efficient way.

Comment: You can always use plain C for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it on main thread. As your user case is simple, I write a simple example. I don't test it by the way...

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) ;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr ;
bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) ;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(1025) ;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.5") ;
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;

int i = connect(sock, (const struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) ;
if (i >= 0) {
    char writeBuf[17] = "12345678901234567" ;
    long w = write(sock, writeBuf, 17) ;
    if (w > 0) {
        char bufferRead[1024] ;
        long r = read(sock, bufferRead, sizeof(bufferRead)) ;
        if (r > 0) {
            // success
        }
    }
}
close(sock) ;
```

Comment: ok your answer is so fast and I'm sure that work fine... but do you have some documentation to see? and can I do the same with GCDAsyncSocket?

Comment: @nazz_areno I advise you to read a book `Unix Network Programming, Volume 1`, it is a very good book which talks about how to program with socket. You can do the same with `GCDAsyncSocket` and You'd better to use `GCDAsyncSocket` if you have complex interaction with the server.